# Should comments implying or stating that "you are asking for too much" be frowned upon?

Tags: discussion

I have seen some comments on questions that state something around the line that:

- what you are asking for, is too much to get for free
- we get paid for questions like that
- we make a living with those types of questions

If a person is looking for help and picks SE because of its awesome community, shouldn't this type of comments be discouraged, or is it totally valid?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> If a person is looking for help and picks SE because of it's awesome community, shouldn't this type of comments be discouraged, or is it totally valid.

Well, IMO these kind of comments shouldn't be posted at all. There's no real value added.

I believe the correct reaction would be to flag/vote the question for closure as *too broad* (assumed the site supports that close reason).

On the other hand, we're encouraged to explain our voting behavior, and give the OP a hint why actually.

One crucial point (misconception) about your question is *"If a person is looking for help"*. Stack Exchange sites aren't designed to be personal helpdesks, or something you can outsource to let others do your required efforts for free.

Answer (score 5):

On SuperUser we regularly close "gimme the scriptz" questions as too broad. If I spot one I also leave the following comment:

> Please note that https://superuser.com is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

And then close the question. If the OP edits appropriately then the question may get reopened.

Comment: IMO your approach is the most professional and straight to the point which I agree. The comments I mentioned were seen from users who have been around for a while and are top ranked, hence my concern.

Comment: I'd add, since David's said most of what needs to be said that the tone, and content matter. We cannot ever forget rule 0.5 - "Be Nice" ;p